# What does ERROR_DLL_INIT_FAILED mean?

Tags: exception, hresult

I'm seeing the following exception in my managed (C#) app calling an unmanaged assembly:

> Caught:System.IO.FileLoadException 'A dynamic link library (DLL) initialization routine failed. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007045A)'

What does this HRESULT mean, and where should I start in diagnosing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

alternatively the DLL you try to load is trying to load a missing DLL, check with [DEPENDS.EXE](http://www.dependencywalker.com/) on the DLL.

Answer (score 4):

I was getting this error after upgrading a solution that was in VS 2008 and had projects targeting .NET framework v2.0 to VS 2010 with target runtime v 4.0. The exception I was getting was:

> Could not load file or assembly 'XYZ.dll' or one of its dependencies. A dynamic link library (DLL) initialization routine failed. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007045A)":"XYZ.dll

This was fixed by adding the following section to the App.config file of the project set as startup:

```
<startup useLegacyV2RuntimeActivationPolicy="true">
   <supportedRuntime version="v2.0"/>
   <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.0"/>
</startup>
```

Comment: That solved it for me, too! Got an error with a managed C++ library to include HtmlTidy. Worked for me after adding your app.config settings. The error only occurred on Windows 8 and only if the application is stored beneath a local path like "C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local". When the application's executable is located somewhere at "C:\Program Files (x86)\..." no error occurred.

Comment: Thanks! This also let me run Boxcryptor on Win8 Pro N 64bit!

Comment: This worked a treat for me!

Answer (score 3):

**FileLoadException Class**

> Represents the error that occurs when
>   a Assembly file is found but cannot be
>   loaded.
>
> The FileNotFoundException exception is
>   thrown when the file fails to load
>   because it cannot be located. If the
>   file is located, but cannot be loaded
>   due to insufficient permissions, a
>   SecurityException is thrown.
>
> FileLoadException has the default
>   HRESULT of COR_E_FILELOAD, which has
>   the value 0x80131621, but this is not
>   the only possible HRESULT.
>
> If your code does not have
>   PathDiscovery permission, the error
>   message for this exception may only
>   contain file or directory names
>   instead of fully qualified paths.

Quoted straight from MSDN:
[link text](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.fileloadexception.aspx)

This is usually simply an issue of being able to find the required library.

Comment: Turns out the error was due to the missing assembly manifest.

Answer (score 0):

I was getting this error on application shutdown.  It appeared to be provoked by the garbage collection "Finalize" method in a control which referenced several COM+ modules and other unmanaged assemblies in multiple DLLs.

I corrected the Dispose method of the control to call GC.SuppressFinalize and also set a flag in the control so that the managed code section only runs once.  I also modified forms using the control so they were always explicitly closed.