# C#: A dynamic link library (DLL) initialization routine failed

Tags: c#, dll, dllimport

I am trying to replicate some functionality of other app, which uses CyStat.dll. Here is the app itself

https://mega.nz/#!sIRggKST!UEeAWgcT9ONbyc0WgFagI-0G36zxvEK1dMwzw3NYd60

It's basically a status monitoring tool for a specific printer

My problem is this: I get this error every time I try to use the dll:

```
'Unable to load DLL 'CyStat.dll': A dynamic link library (DLL) initialization routine failed. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007045A)'
```

I know that usually that is because some dependencies are missing. Here are the dependencies that it uses:

[image]

They are definitely present on my machine, and by the way, original app that I am trying to replicate, works fine

Here is the code I use to call the methods from the dll:

```
    [DllImport("CyStat.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Ansi, SetLastError = true)]
    public static extern int CvInitialize([MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)] string pszPortName);

    var res = CvInitialize("DS-RX1");
```

I also tried decompiling that app and copy-pasting code from there, but it fails with the same error

Thanks in advance for any help

Comment: Is it managing to find the main Dll? is this on your path? So many things might be going wrong. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1747985/what-does-error-dll-init-failed-mean or https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/tess/2009/04/29/unable-to-load-dll-dllname-dll-a-dynamic-link-library-dll-initialization-routine-failed-0x8007045a/ may have some clues.

Comment: @doctorlove I do not see DllMain in there, but it's optional. The first link does not help because it;s not .NET dll, and because I checked dependencies and it seems fine to me (maybe I am stupid and can't see something, than you are welcome to download that dll from the link I provided and check it yourself). Second link does not help because I tried those steps, running with elevated permissions and etc (by the way, original app does not require elevated permissions)

Comment: Why conclude this is an issue with finding dependencies? DllMain can't be involvled with resolving dependencies. If a DllMain fails it is for some other reason.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan can you suggest something? Links provided above to msdn blogs did not helps, cause it's not a component, only single dll, dependencies are fine and running the code with elevated permissions did not help

Comment: Well, a `DllMain` failed. Answer lies in the content of the `DllMain` that failed. You'll need to talk to somebody that has access to the source code for the DLL.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan not happening. This is a japanese company that produced this printer and this software, and software is 10 years old by the looks of it. Also I am sure they won't be happy about me trying to reverse-engenier it
It works fine in their code. What should I look for? Maybe there is some kind of code in the app that does something for dll initialization? Some king of check

Comment: I don't think we can answer this question though. I'm not sure what the question even is.

Comment: I solved it by setting project to x64 and loading x64 version of the dll instead, now it works fine

Comment: Posting images of things needed to solve your problem puts you on the road to question deletion and you are only two votes from that. Never post images of code, errors or output. [mcve]

Comment: @Rob did you see the question, lol? All the code is written, I provided the dll itself and the code I use to call it. Only image is the Dependec Walker output

Comment: Maybe post an answer to your own question, being clear about what exact errors you saw, in case it helps someone else

Comment: @doctorlove sure, just did that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, I had that error in question accompanied by the System.DllNotFoundException, which I did not notice right away
My dll was dependent on kernel32.dll and winspool.drv. When I noticed that exception, I realized that I tried to load 32 bit dll on my 64 bit system. So I just tried 64 bit version and it worked perfectly